# How to get a string of days which is made up of dates (column) only where the value in the table is greater than zero?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need an excel array formula which will create a string made up of days (say "Sun Mon Fri"). The string content will be conditional on a pivot table.

If value in pivot cell is >0, then the date in the corresponding column should be used as an input to that string.

Eg: if one row of my pivot table has values as 1,0,0,0,1,0,0 (and corresponding dates are 10 to 17th Feb). The string should be "Wed Sun ".

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your pivot table row was row 5 and your dates corresponding to each column were in row 4, you could use a formula like this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,TEXT(FILTER($B$4:$H$4,$B$5:$H$5=1),"ddd"))
```

[image]

`FILTER` says "get the values from row 4 where row 5 is equal to 1". `TEXT` converts those dates returned into 3-letter abbreviations for day. `TEXTJOIN` combines the results into a single cell, with each day separated by a space.

EDIT:

To be more specific to your question, you may want the filter criteria to be >0:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,TEXT(FILTER($B$4:$H$4,$B$5:$H$5>0),"ddd"))
```

Comment: Thank you, this will help.